# Finding the background colour System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, graphics

After I've drawn an object in the bitmap, I'd like to move it, so I need to draw the object again in the background colour, before drawing again in the proper colour. Assuming this is the correct approach, how do I find out what the background colour actually is?
Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you draw your object you can only use GetPixel to obtain the colour:

```
Bitmap.GetPixel(x,y)
```

Why not just clearing the whole bitmap and rewriting your object again?
If your bitmap is not extremely large, you won't probably even notice any difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have control on the canvas and if you have a "clean" canvas, you can get the color of any pixel before drawing and that should be your background color.

But remember, you don't have a background color on a regular bitmap, just a bunch of pixels! So if your canvas is not clear, or if you don't have a way to get the color before drawing, you have to make assumptions. There a quite a few solutions depending on your requirements. My suggestions are:

- You can assume the pixel on the corner are your background colors
- The color that appears more often is the background color